# How to generate new type from multiple entities to use in asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-6

If I have two `Domain classes(2 Entities)` like this :

**(1)**

```
public partial class SCIENCEDEGREE
    {
        public SCIENCEDEGREE()
        {
            this.EMPSCIENCEDEGREEs = new HashSet<EMPSCIENCEDEGREE>();
        }

        public int SDEGREE_CODE { get; set; }
        public string DEGREE_NAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SCATEGORY_CODE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> UNIVERISTY_FLAG { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EMPSCIENCEDEGREE> EMPSCIENCEDEGREEs { get; set; }
    }
```

**(2)**

```
 public partial class QUALCATEGORY
    {
        public QUALCATEGORY()
        {
            this.QUALIFICATIONs = new HashSet<QUALIFICATION>();
        }

        public int QUALCATEGORY_CODE { get; set; }
        public string QUALCATEGORY_NAME { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<QUALIFICATION> QUALIFICATIONs { get; set; }
    }
```

---

Now the value of `SCATEGORY_CODE` property in `SCIENCEDEGREE` comes from 
`QUALCATEGORY_CODE` property  in `QUALCATEGORY` entity .

I want to Bind a grid with the following data :

```
SDEGREE_CODE
DEGREE_NAME
SCATEGORY_CODE
UNIVERISTY_FLAG
QUALCATEGORY_NAME //--->from QUALCATEGORY
```

but i don't know how to do this in my architecture :

[image]

---

How to fetch these data prepared to bind on asp.net server control ?

Comment: If `SCIENCEDEGREE.SCATEGORY_CODE` were a foreign key to `QUALCATEGORY.QUALCATEGORY_CODE`, it would be easy to make the link. And you would have the data integrity checking by the same way. You really can't make this property as a foreign key ?

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the SCIENCEDEGREE to have a QUALCATEGORY property and populate this when you create the instance.